# After set minifyEnabled true in debug mode api call not working properly

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

After  **minifyEnabled true** in *build.gradle*

Like below

```
 buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

When i make api call while  **minifyEnabled true** i got success but some Parameters value change which is different from  expected value.

And

When i make api call while  **minifyEnabled false ** i got actual value which comes from back-end side.

(i.e.) i got **isValidUser** parameter in api response which is boolean 
actual value is isValidUser=true which is expected but i got isValidUser=false.

help me what is the problem with my build.gradle file?

Comment: you need to keep your dto classes in proguard or use gson annotation     @SerializedName

Comment: @RutvikBhatt i used okhttp3 library for api call

Comment: yes i   use gson annotation @SerializedName

Comment: just add -keep class YOUR CLASS ** { *; }

Comment: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/practical-proguard-rules-examples-5640a3907dc9 read this

Comment: @PayamKokabi its work for me i need to declare my model file in to  **proguard-rules.pro**

Comment: @PayamKokabi i want to change that line dynamic way when i  change package name it'll reflect  in  **proguard-rules.pro** it's possible?

Comment: usually if you use @SerializedName and keep Gson you wouldnt need to keep your classes althought in some rare cases you need to do both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the help of **Payam Kokabi**,
issue is solved **minifyEnabled true** is will not change the value when we declare 
`-keep class YOUR CLASS ** { *; }` 
in your **proguard-rules.pro** file.

Answer (score 4):

**Please specify exactly what part is not working, but generally its from the models, so exclude them in the rules file as:**

```
# Models
-keepclassmembers class com.example.models.** {*;}

# GSON
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-dontwarn sun.misc.**
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer i have done the same way 
now  i am facing this issue
i just change my package name and in  **proguard-rules.pro**  file we have  to write hard coded in this file any other way to change that line when change package name ?

Comment: @Arbaz.in unfortunately this needs to be hard coded

Answer (score 1):

@Arbaz.in if you use @SerializedName and keep Gson you wouldnt need to keep your classes althought in some rare cases you need to do both 
you can use these proguard rules for your GSON it should work:
[GSON Proguard](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg)

Comment: First i do with @SerializedName but not working that model then i set proguard rules and it's work. thanks for the answer